# floated div drops when height of above DIV is greater than X

Tags: css, html, css-float

css:

```
.listingContainer {
    margin:auto;
    overflow:hidden;
    padding:0 0 16px 16px;
    width:660px;
}

.listingItem {
    float:left;
    margin:0 2% 3% 3%;
    min-height:250px;
    width:44.999%;
}
```

html:

```
<div class="listingContainer">
    <div class="listingItem">
    <p>Some Content</p>
    </div>
    <div class="listingItem">
    <p>Some Content</p>
    </div>
    <div class="listingItem">
    <p>Some Content</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

If the content in any given "listingItem" DIV becomes too great, the div directly below will drop to the NEXT row.

the content looks like:

```
[1] [2]
[3] [4]
[5] [6]
```

but if a div has say 1 extra paragraph in, rather than stagger the divs, it is pushed to the next row:

```
[1] [2]
    [4] 
[3] [5] 
[6]
```

this isProbably working as intended, but how can i fix this? can't provide a live page sorry.

any ideas?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you add a div with clear both, or a row container div to each row it would work, however, like dclowd9901 says, tabular content should be in a table, thats what its for!

Answer (score 0):

Things like this make me itch:

`width:44.999%`

Is there any particular reason you can't just use a (gasp!) table? I'm only curious because, of most designs out there, yours seems like it would actually benefit from a table layout.

Comment: uhmm hadn't really thought about it frankly

but yes that would make far more sense.

I've seen a lot of sites that list content using <divs> so there must be *some* logic behind it?

Comment: Some people are intrinsically against tables in modern design, regardless of how relevant they may be.